# What is the difference between .nextLine() and .next()?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am making a program and am using user input. When I am getting a String I have always used .nextLine(), but I have also used .next() and it does the same thing. What is the difference?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String h = input.nextLine();
String n = input.next();
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Don't ask StackOverflow to read manuals for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798803/understanding-scanners-nextline-next-and-nextint-methods

Answer (score 0):

To make long story short:

**nextLine** - reads the whole line.

**next** - reads until the first space.

As an example:

```
// Input : Barack Obama
String st = in.next(); // st holds the String "Barack"
String st2 = in.nextLine(); //st2 holds the String "Barack Obama"
```

Comment: I was also using them in a for loop and noticed that if you where entering a number before the String then it would skip past the nextLine and it would not skip past the next. Why is this?