# While loop only runs through the body once

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

My While loop is only executing once and it appears it moves back to the top to run through the loop again but only completes the System.out.println("Title"); and then moves on to execute the switch case.  It appear that if I change the int pages = scanner.nextInt(); and the int pub = scanner.nextInt(); to int pages = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()); and int pub = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()); the loop works as expected.  I was wondering if anyone could explain why that is?

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag) {

            System.out.println("Title:");
            String title = scanner.nextLine();

            if (!title.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Pages:");
                int pages = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Publication year:");
                int pub = scanner.nextInt();
                Book info = new Book(title, pages, pub);
                bookList.add(info);

            } else if (title.isEmpty()) {
                flag = false;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("What informaiton will be printed?");
        String choice = scanner.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {

            case "everything":
                if (choice.equals("everything")) {
                    for (Book info : bookList) {
                        System.out.println(info.getTitle() + ", " + info.getPages() + " pages, " + info.getYear());
                    }
                }

            case "name": {
                if (choice.equals("name")) {
                    for (Book infor : bookList) {
                        System.out.println(infor.getTitle());
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is an explanation of the Scanner and its methods in Java. A bit of the search around stackoverflow helped me found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798803/understanding-scanners-nextline-next-and-nextint-methods#:%7E:text=nextLine()%20reads%20the%20remainder,read%20the%20%22%5Cn%22.) which explains it.

Further I have found that new Developers at time ignore the most obvious area of information that is the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which are always helpful to the beginners because once you can read them they make your life much more easier.

To add onto the answer I have borrowed from the mentioned link

> nextLine() reads the remainder of the current line even if it is
> empty.
>
> nextInt() reads an integer but does not read the escape sequence "\n".
>
> next() reads the current line but does not read the "\n".

And you can find this on the documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {

            System.out.println("Title:");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    // new loop - new scanner 
            
            String title = scanner.nextLine();
            if (title.isEmpty()) break;   // exit from loop if entered title is empty

            System.out.println("Pages:");
            int pages = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Publication year:");
            int pub = scanner.nextInt();
            Book info = new Book(title, pages, pub);
            bookList.add(info);
        }
```